# How do you set the state of one component from a different component in react?

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have one component that does not render anything like so:

```
var Application = react.createClass .....

function(....)

module.exports = Application
```

And another component like so:

```
var Tag = react.createClass....
  getInitialState
  //...
  functions
  //...
  setState({ submit: false })
  render: 
  //...
```

I want to change the state of submit in Tag from Application. Is this possible?

Comment: you have to publish events and listen for those events.  https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React JS reference function in another component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054955/react-js-reference-function-in-another-component)

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to change the state of Tags from Application, you really shouldn't do this. Further, I hate these types of answers because I shouldn't tell you bad v.s. good practice, I should just give you the answer you seek.

This is how I would do it.

If you need to set the state of Tags from Applications, you could do 1 of 2 things:

**A.** call setState on Applications, and pass in a specific prop to Tags which you'll check to see if you should setState. You can check this in `componentWillReceiveProps` of Tags. Based on the props received, you can setState. Note, that `componentWillReceiveProps` will not be run when `componentDidMount` runs, so you may need to force it to run by doing something like this at the end of your `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {

    //other code...

    if (this.props.forceReceiveProps === true) {
        this.componentWillReceiveProps(this.props);
    }
}
```

**B.** The other way you could achieve this is use a ref to your Tags from Application.

In Application, you will render something, which probably has Tags. Do something like this:

```
<Tags ref=tagsRef />
```

Then, in some code in Application you can do this:

```
this.refs.tagsRef.setState({})
```

Edit: Actually, upon rereading, it seems you don't render in Application. I assumed it was the parent of your entire app. Not sure why you're not rendering in Application, but it suffices to say you might want to use something like Flux then.